# How to use one _deployment.yml library for multiple versions deployments of same code

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using library charts for my usecase, as template can be used multiple times used this

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
└── templates
    ├── _deployment.yaml
```

below is the definition for `_deployment.yaml`

```yaml
{{- define "library-chart.deployment.tpl" -}}
{{ range `.Values.comp` }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ `.image.name` }}
  {{- if `.image.name` }}
  namespace: {{ `.image.name` }}
  {{- else }}
  namespace: apps
  {{- end }} 
etc....
```

Now my values from component is as below

```yaml
comp:
- image:
    name: compname1
- image:
    name: compname2
```

Now in the template i used range function where it works as foreach and deploy the template 2 times

but it's not working, it's picking only the first image name and deploying but not going in second loop and getting deployed

Comment: How are you calling library-chart.deployment.tpl?